# One Firebase google json config file per app?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I was using admob for my first Android app to display and test banners and interstitials, now that things are involving Firebase, I followed implementation guide and downloaded the google config json file.

I have not yet published my app and wondering, what are situations where I will have to re-download it? App updates or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example. Recently I had to integrate Firebase Push'es and Google Analitycs (not Firebase Analitycs). After each integrated service on Google website console I had to re-download the file, as new services and ID's are added to it.

Each service has it's own part in this file and uses different section.

So this is one case, when this file will have to be re-downloaded.